# Coverity : CSRF is disabled from Spring boot Security but issue is not resolved from coverity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, coverity

Spring boot service exposes one REST End Point and does not have authentication. This will be used internally for microservices inter communication. We have recently added Coverity security scanner and Getting below CSRF issue.

CID 22329 (#1 of 3): Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)

I have disabled CSRF using below code.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.enable-csrf:false}")
    private boolean csrfEnabled;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        if (!csrfEnabled) {
            http.csrf()
                    .disable()
                    /*.ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**")
                    .and()*/
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and().
                    httpBasic();
        }
    }

}
```

Spring boot version 2.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Coverity is warning you that that endpoint is susceptible to CSRF attacks.  If your rest endpoint is not going to be accessed by a browser then you don't need to secure from CSRF attacks.  Coverity will still point it out to you, however you can triage it as "intentional" if it is intentional.  (Adding CSRF protection with spring security is pretty straight forward if you need to add it; if your requirements call for it.)